# Prove that $\int_{π/3}^{π/4}\frac{{\sin x\cos x}}{{1 - 2\cos (2x)}}dx= - \frac{{\log 2}}{8}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int_{π/3}^{π/4}\frac{{\sin x\cos x}}{{1 - 2\cos (2x)}}dx= - \frac{{\log 2}}{8}$$
It tells me to prove this. I inputed both and they both equale to -0.0866. Is this enough to prove it or do I have to make the left side equaled to the right- and if so how do you do this? Any help is much appricated. Thank you!

Comment: This is not enough. With that argument I could state that the integral is in fact -866/10000.

Comment: Just treat it like a normal integral - you will get from the LHS to the RHS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's consider that:  $\sin{x}\cos{x}=\frac{1}{2}\sin{2x}$ and $(-\cos{2x})'=2\sin{2x}$. So:
$$\int_{π/3}^{π/4}\frac{{\sin x\cos x}}{{1 - 2\cos (2x)}}dx= \int_{π/3}^{π/4}\frac{{\frac{1}{2}\sin{2x}}}{{1 - 2\cos (2x)}}dx=\frac{1}{8}\log{(1-2\cos{2x}})\lvert_{\pi/3}^{\pi/4}=0-\frac{\log{2}}{8}$$

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ to be more clear let's observe that,

You should have at the numerator the derivative of $(1-2\cos{2x})$ to be able to solve the integral with the logarithm as I have shown...but the numerator it is not exactly the derivative of the denominator, why? $$(1-2\cos{2x})'=(-2\cos{2x})'=-2\cdot(\cos{2x})'=4\sin{2x}$$ But at the numerator we have $\frac{1}{2}\sin{2x}$ so in effect we can multiply and divide by 4 to obtain the desidered form, in this following way:
$$\int_{π/3}^{π/4}\frac{{\frac{1}{2}\sin{2x}}}{{1 - 2\cos (2x)}}dx=\int_{π/3}^{π/4}\frac{{\frac{\color{red}4}{\color{red}4 \cdot 2}\sin{2x}}}{{1 - 2\cos (2x)}}dx=$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}\int_{π/3}^{π/4}\frac{{4\sin{2x}}}{{1 - 2\cos (2x)}}dx=\Big[\frac{1}{8}\log{(1-2\cos{2x})}\Big]\Big\lvert_{\pi/3}^{\pi/4}$$

Comment: where did the 1/8 come from?

Comment: @Emily I have edited my answer with the explanation! Tell me if now it is clear

Comment: i took my time to look at this question and you made it so clear thank you so much you have no idea how much you have helped me.:)

Comment: @Emily You're welcome I am happy that now it is all clear! :)

Answer (score 2):

So, just calculate this integral:

1. notice that $\sin(x)\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$
2. in your integral put $\cos(2x) = t$ then $-2\sin(2x)dx = dt$
   What will we have?